# Clojure: Find all vectors where function evaluates to true

Tags: clojure

I am attempting to find all elements in a vector where a particular function evaluates to true. My failed attempt is below. Ideas?

```
(defn find-matches [match-fn elements]
  (map-indexed 
    (fn [idx elem] 
      (if (= true (apply match-fn elem))
      [idx elem])
  elements))

(find-matches even? [1 2 3 4]) ; -> Arity Exception Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core$map-indexed clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity
```

Comment: Please recollect that `map` and `map-indexed` produce a new sequence one-for-one with the elements of their sequence arguments. You need something like `filter` or `keep-indexed` or a `:when` clause in a `for` (as the answers severally employ) to keep some elements and discard others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing the last paren on your `fn` invocation.

Further, apply only works on collections, just use the function on single items.

```
user> 
(defn find-matches [match-fn elements]
  (map-indexed 
    (fn [idx elem] 
      (if (= true (match-fn elem))
      [idx elem]))
    elements))

#'user/find-matches
user> (find-matches even? [1 2 3 4])
(nil [1 2] nil [3 4])
```

Finally, I'd switch to keep-indexed so we can ignore the nil elements, and use the general clojure convention of using any non-falsey value in tests (thus we don't need `(= true x)`, x alone suffices).

```
user> 
(defn find-matches [match-fn elements]
  (keep-indexed 
    (fn [idx elem] 
        (if (match-fn elem)
            [idx elem]))
    elements))

#'user/find-matches
user> (find-matches even? [1 2 3 4])
([1 2] [3 4])
```

Comment: Thank you. This most precisely answered my question and was very enlightening about Clojure conventions and idiomatic development.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [filter](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/filter)

```
(def my-vec [1 2 5 9 10 15 22])
(filter even? my-vec)
=> (2 10 22)
```

If instead you wanted the indices:

```
(for [[idx elem] (map vector (range) my-vec)
      :when (even? elem)]
  idx)
=> (1 4 6)
```

Or both:

```
(filter (comp even? second) (map vector (range) my-vec))
=>  ([1 2] [4 10] [6 22])
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is a sequence of numbers. We can erase the unwanted entries by mapping them to `nil` then filtering them out.

```
(defn find-matches [pred coll]
  (filter identity (map-indexed #(when (pred %2) %1) coll)))
```

Any value but a non-negative integer would do as the [black spot](http://www.online-literature.com/stevenson/treasureisland/3/), but a false one such as `nil` makes the filtering trivial.

For example,

```
(find-matches
  #(.startsWith % "b")
  (clojure.string/split "It's a braw bricht moonlicht nicht the nicht" #" "))
;(2 3)
```

The result is lazy, so it can cope with an infinite sequence:

```
(take 10 (find-matches even? (iterate inc 43)))
;(1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19)
```

You can wrap it in `vec` if you want to dump the whole of a finite result in a vector:

```
(vec (find-matches even? [1 2 3 4]))
;[1 3]
```